# CSS Hover Caption Issue

Tags: html, css, hover

- I have a my site background seperated into 4 divs so they each take
  up 25% of the page
- The goal is to have an overlay fade in when hovered over (which I applied to the first image - #nw)
- The problem is that I cannot get the text from class .caption to show up

The code is below:

**CSS**

```
.overlaytext {font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;}
body { height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }
div.bg { position:fixed; width:50%; height:50% }
#NW { top:0;   left:0;   background-image: url('clevelandnight.jpg'); background-size:cover;}
#NE { top:0;   left:50%; background-image: url('news1.jpg'); background-size:cover;}
#SW { top:50%; left:0;   background-image: url('drinks1.jpg'); background-size:cover;}
#SE { top:50%; left:50%; background-image: url('clevelandday.jpg'); background-size:cover;}

.overlay {
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.75);
  opacity:0;
  height:100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-out;  
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease-out;  
  -o-transition: all .4s ease-out;  
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease-out;  
  transition: all .4s ease-out;  
}
#nw:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  height:100%;
}
.caption {
font-color:white;
z-index:100;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>Craig Does Cleveland</title>
    <link href='stylesheet2.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='nw' class='bg'>
      <div class='overlay'>
      </div>
        <span class='caption'>Hello World</span>
    </div>
    <div id='ne' class='bg'>
      <div class='overlay'>
        <span class='caption'>Hello World</span>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div id='sw' class='bg'>
      <div class='overlay'>
        <span class='caption'>Hello World</span>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div id='se' class='bg'>
      <div class='overlay'>
        <span class='caption'>Hello World</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In your HTML markup, the 4 divs are not the same, change the first one to another:

```
<div id='nw' class='bg'>
    <div class='overlay'>
        <span class='caption'>Hello World</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

2) In your CSS, you used ID with uppercase, in your HTML they are in lowercase, change them:

```
#nw { top:0;   left:0;   background-image: url('clevelandnight.jpg'); background-size:cover;}
#ne { top:0;   left:50%; background-image: url('news1.jpg'); background-size:cover;}
#sw { top:50%; left:0;   background-image: url('drinks1.jpg'); background-size:cover;}
#se { top:50%; left:50%; background-image: url('clevelandday.jpg'); background-size:cover;}
```

3) You wrote `hover` only for the first element (`nw`), change it to work for all:

```
.bg:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
    height:100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xzL3bwph/).

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. Is there any way to have the caption fade in after the overlay? I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: @czmudzin Yes, it's possible, see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzL3bwph/1/).